# Unsupported media type formatter when sending JSON-LD

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, json-ld, mediatypeformatter

I am sending JSON LD data using HttpClient in C# to a webapi end point.
I get the error unsupported media type formatter.
The data I am sending is JSONLD as a string:

```
string data = @"{
                      ""@type"": ""vcx:blah"",
                      ""vcx:key"": ""blah"",
                      ""vcx:value"": ""blah""
                 } ";
httpClient.PostAsync(uri, new StringContent(data));
```

On the api side, is web api. In the Global.asax.cs I have the following:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Clear();
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(new 
JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
```

Even if i remove the clearing of the formatters I get the same error on the calling application.

Anyone know the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.stringcontent.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_Http_StringContent__ctor_System_String_System_Text_Encoding_System_String_)

You are using the first constructor of [`StringContent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.stringcontent?view=netframework-4.8), it means that the media type for the `StringContent` created defaults to `text/plain`

If you need jsono then specify media type:

```
httpClient.PostAsync(uri, new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
```

Comment: This enables me to now hit the api endpoint however the string parameter is null. Here is my endpoint signature:                                                                                          
public HttpResponseMessage PostJSONLD([FromBody] string request)

Comment: Actually if I use an object rather than a string on the api side as a parameter, I get it populated.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context